# How to create a file in dist directory that can be altered and that impact the application?

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, build, vite

I'm using React with Typescript and Vite in my application and I have a demand that is: after the build, I need to have a file (e.x: globalStyles.css) that have some variables (like: errorColor, borderColor...) that is used in the source code. And when I change something at this file, the application change that part.
.
I searached but found nothing, is it possible?
If yes, can anyone give me a direction?
.
My thanks in advance

Did some google but didn't find a path to achieve this question./

Comment: Do you want to rebuild your vite app after a file changes?

Comment: @Undo No, I can't do that, I build it once and if I need to change some basic style, i change in that file.

Comment: That's an anti-pattern but if you really need to do it, place a style.css file in /public. Import it somewhere, after building, you can edit style.css in the `build` folder

Comment: @Undo Thanks, I thought in that solution but I think I don't have another way 

Comment: @Undo If you don't mind, could you explain to me why's it an anti-pattern?

Comment: the `dist` folder is not meant to be modified. The correct way to "modify" it is by building it anew, now every time you build you will override changes made to it.